# What would be an alternative for window.URL in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, url

I'm now using [window.URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/URL) object to work with url:

```
var url = new window.URL(text);
return url.host + url.pathname;
```

but it looks like IE does not completely support it.

What universal solution could you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use parseURI.js by Steven Levithan: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/parseuri

It's small but comprehensive. To use it to do the same job as your snippet:

```
var url = parseUri(text);
return url.host + url.path;
```

Comment: Great answer.  I change the properties to match that of URL class available in Chrome and added some missing properties such as origin.

Answer (score 1):

I use this one as a backup for IE, this is an implementation of w3c specs maintained by PolymerJS
https://github.com/webcomponents/URL